# ONSEN UI and Jquery Mobile

Tags: onsen-ui

I'm looking for a way to incorporate Jquery Mobile UI elements into my cordova app, but I'm running into a problem with being unable to access JQuery Mobile data-roles due to the ONSEN ui(angular) routing methods.

Here's an example of the HTML I would like Jquery mobile to render out:

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
        <h4>Lorem</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

I'm assuming I'm going to need to write an ONSEN UI directive to be able to pull this off, but I could really use some help here.

Posts like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937799/angularjs-and-jquery-mobile) are leading me in the right direction but I'm having trouble accomplishing this for ONSEN. What should I do?

Comment: What is a trouble you meet? Please show your code.

Answer (score 3):

This has been already addressed in [HERE.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827570/jquery-mobile-vs-angularjs-page-navigation) Onsen UI is UI framework based on AngularJS.

Personally, I don't recommend using both jQueryMobile and AngularJS at a time. So I recommend you to leave jQueryMobile and use AngularJS and Onsen UI only.

Comment: not even personally, it's really a bad practice, because they almost do the same thing, you should use one, or the other. it's like using two antivirus, there will be some conflicts